# Cannot use # in url launcher (speed dial)

Tags: dart, flutter

i use url launcher for speed dial , but i can't use #. The character after # not show, how to use # in url launcher ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try encoding the value passed to methods of url launcher.

Refer the [link](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.1/dart-core/Uri/encodeComponent.html) for info on how to encode component using `Uri` .